How Does the Store Buffer Drain in x86 Architecture Work?
The topic of the Store Buffer (SB) and its mechanics, size, purpose, and interaction with other buffers has been discussed on Stack Overflow several times. However, certain aspects of its operation seem to remain unclear. One such area that I find puzzling is the process of committing (or "draining") entries from the Store Buffer into the L1d cache of the processor core.
I’d like to ask experts to shed light on this process, particularly in the context of the x86 architecture.
Context
In the Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3, Section 13.10 "STORE BUFFER," the following description is provided:

Intel 64 and IA-32 processors temporarily store each write (store) to memory in a store buffer. The store buffer improves processor
performance by allowing the processor to continue executing
instructions without having to wait until a write to memory and/or to
a cache is complete. It also allows writes to be delayed for more
efficient use of memory-access bus cycles.
In general, the existence of the store buffer is transparent to software, even in systems that use multiple processors. The processor
ensures that write operations are always carried out in program order.
It also ensures that the contents of the store buffer are always
drained to memory in the following situations:

When an exception or interrupt is generated.
(P6 and more recent processor families only) When a serializing instruction is executed.
When an I/O instruction is executed.
When a LOCK operation is performed.
(P6 and more recent processor families only) When a BINIT operation is performed.
(Pentium III, and more recent processor families only) When using an SFENCE instruction to order stores.
(Pentium 4 and more recent processor families only) When using an MFENCE instruction to order stores.

The discussion of write ordering in Section 10.2, “Memory Ordering,” gives a detailed description of the operation of the store buffer.

As described, the Store Buffer appears to drain under specific conditions triggered by particular instructions and operations. However, the exact mechanism of this "draining" is not elaborated on in the manual, leading to some confusion and debates on the topic.
Core Questions

Do these instructions explicitly trigger a flush of the buffer (commit entries into the cache), or do they simply enforce a delay, allowing the buffer to drain naturally as part of its automatic operation?
What happens to the drained entries?

Do they persist in the buffer for some time after the commit?
If so, what purpose do they serve by remaining in the buffer?
Can these entries be reused, or is there an optimization in "batch removal" when it comes to clearing buffer space?



My Initial Understanding (Likely Oversimplified)
Given the limited size of the Store Buffer, I assume there must be a mechanism to free up space for new entries. This could result in an automatic commit of entries to the L1d cache in FIFO order, triggered by natural pressure on the buffer’s capacity.
Meanwhile, the above-mentioned instructions (e.g., LOCK, SFENCE, MFENCE) might enforce a forced commit to guarantee the specific semantics they are designed to provide, such as memory ordering and memory barrier semantics.
This explanation might be overly simplified or even incorrect. Hence, I’d greatly appreciate insights from more knowledgeable members of the community.
Desired Clarifications

What is the precise process for draining the Store Buffer?
Are there distinctions between automatic and instruction-triggered draining mechanisms?
Does the buffer retain entries after a commit, and if so, why?
How do these mechanisms interplay with the guarantees provided by instructions like LOCK, MFENCE, or SFENCE?

Thank you in advance for any insights you can provide to clarify these aspects of the Store Buffer’s operation in x86 processors.

The store buffer is always trying to drain itself as fast as it can; barrier instructions just wait for that to happen. Or SFENCE just puts a divider into the store buffer like a grocery-store checkout conveyor belt, so it orders NT stores wrt. normal stores, but later loads don't have to wait for it. Why is (or isn't?) SFENCE + LFENCE equivalent to MFENCE?

also related: Can a speculatively executed CPU branch contain opcodes that access RAM? re: what a store buffer is: a circular buffer of entries allocated in program order.  And on x86, also freed in program order since the memory model requires it.

@PeterCordes So, the barrier simply prevents reordering and waits until the writes that are programmatically ordered before the barrier instruction are committed to the cache memory? The instruction does not initiate the commit itself but enforces waiting for it to complete?

@PeterCordes I just can’t wrap my head around this conceptually. If we strive to empty the storage buffer as quickly as possible, then why do we even fill it up in the first place? Based on this, as I understand it, we don’t necessarily need to wait for it to be fully filled to commit, right? Is there really no trigger that determines, even automatically, that now is precisely the time for that commit?

Cache miss stores can't commit to L1d cache until we get MESI exclusive ownership of the cache line, and the data is there to merge the new dword into, so clean/dirty status is only tracked on a per-line basis.  Stores don't write whole lines, they write a few bytes inside a cache line. (Except for AVX-512 ZMM stores.)

@PeterCordes I think I understand. You correctly pointed out that a situation may arise where, to modify a cache line, it will be necessary to ensure exclusive access to it, which means invoking the cache coherence protocol. All of this takes a non-zero amount of time, which also makes sense. As a result, to avoid idly waiting, we can continue filling the buffer if we have something to put into it, utilizing speculative computations. Nevertheless, as soon as we are ready to complete the write operation, we will do so without delays. Did I grasp the idea correctly?

Pretty much.  If you already have the line in Modified or Exclusive state, no off-core communication is necessary, otherwise it is.  Like I wrote in Can a speculatively executed CPU branch contain opcodes that access RAM?, the primary purposes of a store buffer are to decouple execution from cache-miss stores (like Intel mentioned in your quote from the manual).  And for an out-of-order exec CPU, to make speculative exec of stores possible at all.  The store buffer isn't a cache; you don't want entries sitting around any longer than necessary.

@PeterCordes Thank you for the helpful links! I’ve already read through half of them, but I have to keep rereading because the topic isn’t as simple as it seemed. Alright, we have limitations on the buffer size. On my old laptop with a Sandy Bridge processor, it’s around 36 entries, as I learned from one of your responses. If the buffer gets completely filled, will we temporarily be unable to perform speculation?

Yup, that'll stall the front-end on the next store instruction that reaches issue/rename/alloc, when it's unable to allocate a SB entry.

@DmytroKostenko: Keep in mind there are two possibilities.  It could be that the cache line is present in L1 cache but not owned by this core, in which case it takes some time to gain ownership (RFO).  The other is that it is not present in L1 cache at all (cache miss), in which case it may take a much longer time, up to hundreds of cycles, to fetch it from lower-level cache or DRAM.  You would really like the CPU to continue doing useful work during that time.

@PeterCordes How do instructions with memory barrier semantics understand how long they need to wait to avoid, for example, performing a read operation that is located after the barrier? The point is that such instructions add that very separator you mentioned, correct? How can it be represented? Is it something like a label? A kind of metadata?

@NateEldredge I think I'm starting to grasp the idea. If we simplify it completely and put it bluntly, am I right in understanding that, under ideal conditions where we always have no cache misses and we are the sole owner of the cache line, the store buffer is not really needed, even conceptually?

You need a store buffer for speculative exec of stores.  An in-order CPU doesn't need a store buffer under ideal conditions.  Re: barriers, that could be implemented as a special store-buffer entry that forces any LFBs (line fill buffers) holding NT store data to flush, before any later stores commit.  And which an mfence instruction can wait for before it retires, also blocking later loads.  Instead of the usual thing where stores only commit after they retire.

@PeterCordes Thank you for the explanations! I think I'm slowly starting to understand. As I see it, an instruction with memory barrier semantics adds a special dummy entry to the Store Buffer. Logically, this entry doesn't contain any actual data (it's completely empty) but might include additional metadata that indicates its special purpose. The Store Buffer won't proceed further until all other write operations before this "special" entry are completed. In other words, we should not expect progress at the SB level until this condition is met.

@PeterCordes At the same time, the commit process—defined as the "completion" of a write operation—always occurs from the LFB, as the Store Buffer is only meant for temporary storage and not for direct writing to the cache or main memory. And by the way, what happens to the entries in the SB in the end? I've heard that they can remain in the buffer for some time. Or are they automatically removed after the data write operation is completed?

SB entries are removed ASAP, as soon as they're committed.  Each load (up to 3/clock) has to snoop every SB entry (https://blog.stuffedcow.net/2014/01/x86-memory-disambiguation/) in case it's reloading a recent store, so making the SB larger to hide bursts of stores is much more expensive than making L1d cache bigger.  I have a lot of an answer written but got stalled editing it: this discussion in comments has proved useful to see which explanations are working.

@PeterCordes I'm glad that our discussion is proving to be constructive! Indeed, there is a lack of clear, low-level details for those who might be interested in this topic. There are many speculations regarding the behavior of store buffers. My question about storage wasn’t random; in fact, I’ve come across information online suggesting that the buffer supposedly continues to store entries for quick access—something akin to being a part of the store-to-load forwarding mechanism.

@PeterCordes Because of this, some authors claim that such storage would be beneficial and might have even been envisioned as part of the architecture from the very beginning.

@PeterCordes And of course, the greatest classic of all time, which, in part, inspired me to ask this question! This is the speculation of certain individuals about data visibility issues between the caches of multiple cores, which is especially relevant in multithreaded programming. Allegedly, the infamous "store buffer" is the root of all problems, and if it isn't flushed (it was assumed that this process was manually regulated and controlled via instructions, as I initially believed when formulating this question), then we might encounter the dreaded issue where changes are never seen.

@PeterCordes It turns out that this assumption doesn’t align with reality at all! Yes, delays can certainly occur, but the complete inability to see changes? That appears to be purely a result of reordering in very specific scenarios—and even then, not universally.

At the very least, for correctness, the store buffer entry must be invalidated when the L1 cache line leaves the exclusive state.  Otherwise you would indeed get "complete inability to see changes" and the architectural memory model forbids that.

@NateEldredge Yes, that's fair. It could violate data consistency. I also immediately thought that leaving entries there would be illogical, if only because the size of this buffer is quite limited.

Yeah, stores do become visible to loads in asm; threads are only run across cores that share a cache-coherent view of memory on any ISA.  (ARM Boards with non-coherent caches exist, but for separate cores like microcontroller and DSP, where you wouldn't run threads of the same program across them.)  In higher-level languages like C, that's not the case if you don't use _Atomic (or volatile), because compilers can optimize values into registers, which are thread-private.

I've seen one user claim that ARM allows repeated stores to the same address to keep coalescing in the store buffer and never commit to cache, delaying visibility indefinitely.
But I don't think that's plausible for a real design; they didn't respond to a request to back up their claim with a demo of the effect.  (I think store coalescing would normally be done by having the commit stage look at the 2 or 4 SB entries closest to the head and see if they were all part of the same aligned word or 8byte or whatever, so even repeated stores would still result in commits.)

@NateEldredge: An SB entry isn't invalidated without commit when this core loses Exclusive / Modified ownership of the line.  The store definitely has to happen (and become part of the modification-order for that location).  It still will, just not yet.  When that entry reaches the head of the SB and misses in L1d cache (because the line is Invalid or only Shared; only E or M state can hit for stores), this core has to do a Read For Ownership (RFO) and wait until it does own the line, then commit.

@PeterCordes: Yes, of course.  I meant that if you had a design where the store buffer entry remained active after commit (e.g. because store-forwarding loads were faster than L1 cache loads), then it could only stay there as long as the cache line remained in M or S state (not E, that was a mistake).  If the cache line is later invalidated, because another core is writing to it, then the already-committed store buffer entry has to be invalidated too.

@NateEldredge: Ohhh, yes, that would be true in a crazy design that spent some of its precious few SB entries keeping around values that were already in cache, perhaps if store-forwarding had much lower latency than L1d cache hits.  So using some SB entries as a fully-associative L0 cache I guess, since loads already have to snoop the store buffer.

Btw, the ARM architectural memory model (at least for ARMv8) does promise that writes complete in finite time, so an implementation that could delay visibility indefinitely would be broken.

@NateEldredge: SB space is precious, but opportunistically leaving an entry available for reading until it's reallocated for a new store is actually plausible.  (Not worth it because then it has to monitor a cache line for invalidation, good point.)  I wonder if real designs save power by gating the compares from SB entries that aren't in use?  They need to avoid false-positive matches somehow, and a way that has fewer gates switching would save power. And thanks for the ARM memory model detail; glad to hear there's a guarantee which also prevents starvation of any writer even with contention.

@NateEldredge Indeed, it seems that among the more or less popular processor architectures, the scenario where a value could indefinitely remain in one of the buffers is entirely excluded. At least, it seems unlikely to reproduce such a case in practice. So, if I were to claim that the only potential source of visibility issues is reordering, would that statement sound too presumptuous? Objectively, based on the discussion, this seems closer to the truth.

@PeterCordes Interesting, are there any known cases where one of the buffers is indeed used for reading data, functioning somewhat like an L0 cache? As far as I understand, this is not typical for processors based on the x86 architecture, correct?

@NateEldredge I would like to clarify one more nuance for confirmation, if I may. Based on everything written above, can we conclude that the entries in the Store Buffer are removed immediately after the commit, following the principle of "as quickly as practically possible"? That is, once committed, they are removed almost immediately as the next action, if we were to represent this in some sort of algorithmic form. And reading an entry from the buffer via store-to-load forwarding is still possible, but only before the commit.
